# Generating absolute url to action from within Api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

im working with asp.net mvc4 and i have in 'controller1' this action :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Action1()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
            string uri = "controller2/action2";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await cl.GetAsync(uri);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return response.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

when i set uri to `"http://localhost:1733/controller2/action2"` the action works fine, BUT never with uri set to "controller2/action2" or "/controller2/action2" or "~/controller2/action2".

how can i write this action without hardcoding the uri ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
string uri = Url.Action("Action2", "Controller2", new {}, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

**Update:**

Since you're using an API controller and need to generate a Url to a regular controller, you're gonna have to use:

```
string uri = this.Url.Link("Default", new { controller = "Controller2", action = "Action2" });
```

Where `Default` is the name of the `route` defined in your registered routes collection, or if you already created a specific route for this action, use it's name and `new{}` as the 2nd parameter.

For MVC version 4, check your registered routes at `~/App_Start/RoutesConfig.cs`. for MVC version 3, check your `RegisterRoutes` method in your `Global.asax`.

Comment: 'System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and no extension method 'Action' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: im a missing some reference ?

Comment: The action you want to generate absolute Url to, is it WebApi method or a regular controller action?

Comment: no its inside a regular controller. and as i said with this one `"http://localhost:1733/controller2/action2"` the action works, i just dont want to hardcode my action

Comment: Important bit here is the `Url.Link`. `Url.Route` generates relative urls.

Answer (score 14):

Another, perhaps simpler answer, is to create an instance of UrlHelper in your WebApi class:

```
var url = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
item.Url = url.Action("Doc", "Editor", new {id=1});
```

Pass in the current request context and you are gold.